# In MySQL, how can I extract years from a column of inconsistently inputted dates as strings?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string, date

Migrating data over to a new database, and want to start on the right note. Previous developer let users manually enter date ranges, and stored everything in one column as a string. Formats include (but not limited to):

```
September 2008 – March 2010 

May 2015 – Present

2007 – 2008

July, 1995 – March, 1997

July, 1995 – Current
```

Yes, it's pretty ugly. Moving forward, I want to split these up into two columns, a startDate and endDate, so that information can be dynamically created. The only consistent pattern that I can find is that all startDates include the year, and all endDates include either the year or indicate that range is still growing. The other pattern is that each date can be split at the ' - ' pattern. If there is an easy way to extract months, I'm happy to look into it, but the months aren't important for this purpose, so an answer extracting the year is more than enough.

Comment: Are those included into one column right now?

Comment: Yep. All under a column of 'years' (VARCHAR(255). Want to convert them to DATE (and just assume a Jan 1 month/day)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select (case when substring_index(col, ' - ', 1) regexp '^[0-9]{4}$'
             then substring_index(col, ' - ', 1)
             when substring_index(col, ' - ', 1) regexp '[0-9]{4}$'
             then right(substring_index(col, ' - ', 1), 4)
             else 'Unknown'
        end) as startYear,
       (case when substring_index(col, ' - ', -1) regexp '^[0-9]{4}$'
             then substring_index(col, ' - ', -1)
             when substring_index(col, ' - ', -1) regexp '[0-9]{4}$'
             then right(substring_index(col, ' - ', -1), 4)
             when substring_index(col, ' - ', -1) like '%Current%' or
                  substring_index(col, ' - ', -1) like '%Present%'
             then date_format(now(), '%Y')
             else 'Unknown'
        end) as endYear
```

You might need additional logic, if you find `'Unknown'` values in the resulting columns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "**but not limited to**" statement. Without definite limits on the possible format types, you're in trouble for a fully automated conversion.

In order to to accomplish this, what I would do is create a conversion table in the new database, with just your key column, the original values, your new start and end date columns, and an additional status column. Since you can't fully automate things, create a place where you can automate as much as possible and manually review just what needs manual review. Don't try to accomplish it all in a SQL statement. Use procedural SQL or a client program to look at each record, classify the original format based on what you find is most common, do the conversion as best it can based on the classification, and update the record with the converted values and the status.

Once that is done, you can work the remaining data by hand to get what you couldn't automate. And once all of the columns have converted, you then push the data to the final table and can drop the conversion tables.